# Accessible web datagrid?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, accessibility

I'm building a budget webapp, mostly for my personal needs and for the sake of self training. I may release it later at some point.

The interface will feature a table of operations (credit / debit). I was planning to use Ajax to make the table "editable" by clicking in a cell (Excel-like).
I therefore need to:

- diplay operations
- add new ones
- modify existing ones

I fail to see how to make "modify" degrade nicely, as if you remove JS, this will be a plain old table without the possibility to modify an existing entry.

Turning the table into a giant form would be ugly, adding links to edit each operation then hide them using JS seems fairly complex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to add links that go to other forms that allow the modify operations to take place. This is much less fluid than in-place edits for accounts, but it still remains accessible without being burdensome (like a huge page of form inputs would be).

You can then override the links with javascript to give the ajaxy, web-app functionality you are looking for.